# Pop up function for Struts1.2 Java web application

Tags: java, struts

We are using struts 1.2 and java and it is web based application. After 10 mins of user login, a pop-up for survey has to come up.

Here is my code:

I am using the timer to log 10 mins in LoginAction.java

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          //code here
          JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, surveyMessage, surveyTitle, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
         //rest of the code
        },  10 * 60 * 1000);
```

It is working in my local. but when deployed to server, below exception popped up

```
    Exception in thread "Timer-34" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1758)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1833)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1696)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:863)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:795)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(JOptionPane.java:757)
    at com.web.actions.LoginAction$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `JOptionPane` is Swing; that is not a web technology. You need to use JavaScript, on the client (browser), for things like this.

Comment: You can't run this code on server.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you tell me what exactly I need to use in javascript

Comment: @Shr No, because there are a *lot* of options for client-side UI. You'll also need to decide if that 10 minutes is per-screen or per-session; if it's per-session you'll need to have something on the client that tracks session time across windows/tabs (and has something that indicates that the timeout has expired that'll be checked before popping up the survey, so it doesn't pop up across the other windows/tabs).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have got that timer covered at session level. I am looking for options to get the pop up displayed

Comment: @Shr Then you'll need to choose between any of the JS options for popups; there are dozens.

Comment: I cannot forward it to a different jsp. so trying to find a pop up that can come up from java class.

Comment: @Shr That isn't how the web works. You could conceivably use the server side to tell the client to pop up a JS element (web sockets, continuous polling, etc.) but other than the server telling the client (browser) to do something, that is impossible. Java runs on the server. JS runs on the client (browser).